# Перечисления в java.

Tags: java

Изучаю java. Дошёл до перечислений, и тут просто вынос мозга творится. Если я что-то неправильно напишу (а далее я пишу так, как сам всё понял), то исправьте и объясните, пожалуйста.

```
enum Size { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, EXTRA_LARGE; }
```

В этой строке компилятор создал 4 экземпляра класса Size, которые содержат имена констант перечисления и их порядковые номера с помощью некоторого конструктора класса Size, который наследуется от этого конструктора суперкласса:

```
protected Enum(String name, int ordinal);
```

Создавать где-нибудь ещё экземпляра класса Size я не могу, т.к. нет конструктора с подходящим ключом доступа. Допустим, тут ещё всё более-менее ясно.  Я пошёл дальше:

```
package main;

    enum Size
    {
        SMALL(10), MEDIUM(20), LARGE(30), EXTRA_LARGE(40);

        private int size;

        Size(int size)
        {
            //super("Name", 1);
            this.size = size;
        }

        int getSize() { return size; }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String... args)
        {
            Size size = Size.SMALL;
            //Size size1 = new Size(3);
        }   
    }
```

Тогда непонятно:
Почему компилятор не пропускает super("Name", 1) в конструкторе класса Size. Ведь вызываемый мной конструктор в суперклассе Enum объявлен как protected. Кроме того, он не является конструктором по умолчанию и он единственный в суперклассе Enum. Т.е. я ОБЯЗАН его вызвать явным образом!!!

И ещё не понятно:

Компилятор не пропускает Size size1 = new Size(3) , хотя я нахожусь в том же пакете!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы немного глубоко лезете. Ключевое слово `enum` это в некотором роде синтаксический сахар.

> Почему компилятор не пропускает super("Name", 1) в конструкторе класса Size.

Потому что, вы объявляете `Size` не как `class Size extends Enum`, а как `enum Size`. С точки зрения проверки типов никакого явного наследования тут нет и доступ к родительскому конструктору `Enum(String name, int ordinal)` вам никто не даст.

> Т.е. я ОБЯЗАН его вызвать явным образом!!!

Зачем столько экспрессии ). Не обязаны, так как ничего не наследуете.

> Компилятор не пропускает Size size1 = new Size(3)

Конечно не пропускает. Нельзя создавать экземпляры enum-а через `new`. Все необходимые экземпляры объявляются в самом enum-e, и это прекрасно.